# Mi Metodo boolean Validar no me da la salida esperada

Tags: java

He realizado tres clases (`Leer`,`Coche`y `Main`). `Leer`es una entrada por teclado a través de un método que devuelve un Objeto, que inicializa los atributos que hay en la clase `Coche`.

En la Clase `Coche` hay dos Objetos (`c1` y `c2`), con sus respectivos métodos `constructores`, `set` y `get`.

Dentro de la `Clase` Coche he creado un metodo `Validar`, que su funcion es devolver `true` o `false` dependiendo si la respuesta es Si o No. Pero siempre me devuelve `false` y no consigo solucionarlo.

**Clase Leer**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Leer {

    public static Coche readDetalles() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        Coche detalles = new Coche ();

         System.out.println("Dime...¿En que modelo estas pensando?");
         detalles.setModelo(sc.nextLine());

         System.out.println("¿Que color le gustaria?");
         detalles.setColor(sc.nextLine()); 

         System.out.println("¿El color lo vas a querer metalizado? Si o No");
         detalles.setMetalizar(sc.nextLine());

         System.out.println("¿Que matricula vas a querer?");
         detalles.setMatricula(sc.nextLine());

         System.out.println("¿En que tipo de coche estabas pensando..? Familiar, Deportivo, Mini o Utilitario");
         detalles.setTipoDeCoche(sc.nextLine());

         System.out.println("¿Que tipo de seguro quiere para su coche?");
         detalles.setSeguro(sc.nextLine());

         return detalles;

    }
}
```

**Clase Coche**

```
public class Coche {

    private String modelo;
    private String color;
    private boolean metalizado;
    private String matricula;
    private String tipoDeCoche;
    private String seguro;
    private String metalizar;

    public Coche() {
    }

    public Coche(String modelo , String color , Boolean metalizado , String matricula , String tipoDeCoche , String seguro , String metalizar) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.color = color;
        this.metalizado = metalizado;
        this.matricula = matricula; 
        this.tipoDeCoche = tipoDeCoche;
        this.seguro = seguro;
        this.metalizar = metalizar;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Boolean getMetalizado() {
        return metalizado;
    }

    public void setMetalizado(Boolean metalizado) {
        this.metalizado = metalizado;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getTipoDeCoche() {
        return tipoDeCoche;
    }

    public void setTipoDeCoche(String tipoDeCoche) {
        this.tipoDeCoche = tipoDeCoche;
    }

    public String getSeguro() {
        return seguro;
    }

    public void setSeguro(String seguro) {
        this.seguro = seguro;
    }

    public String getMetalizar() {
        return metalizar;
    }

    public void setMetalizar(String metalizar) {
        this.metalizar = metalizar;
    }

    public boolean Validar() {
        if(this.metalizar == "Si") { 
            metalizado = true;
        }else if(this.metalizar == "No") {
            metalizado = false;
        }

        return metalizado;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String salida = "Tipo de Modelo :" + this.modelo + "\n" + "Color :" + this.color + "\n" + "Metalizado :" + this.metalizado + "\n" + "Numero de Matricula :" + this.matricula + "\n" + "Tipo de Coche :" + this.tipoDeCoche + "\n" + "Seguro :" + this.seguro;                    

        return salida;
    }
}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coche c1 = Leer.readDetalles();
        Coche c2 = new Coche();

        System.out.println(c1.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso ocurre porque para comparar cadenas en Java tienes que usar [**`equals`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), y estás usando `==`, por tanto la comparación no te dará nunca verdadera.

Si lo escribes así debería funcionar:

```
public boolean Validar() {

 if(this.metalizar.equals("Si")) {

     metalizado = true;

 }else if(this.metalizar.equals("No")) {

     metalizado = false;

 }

 return metalizado;

}
```

Incluso puedes simplificar el método poniendo una sola línea:

```
public boolean Validar() {
    return this.metalizar.equals("Si");
}
```

Ahí devolverá `true` cuando `metalizar` sea `Si` y en caso contrario devolverá `false`, sencillamente porque **`equals` devuelve un booleano**, como puedes ver en la documentación  (enlace más arriba).

Y puedes simplificar más aún a nivel de diseño, declarando `metalizar` de tipo booleano.

Comment: Pues muchisimas gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: @TALBARA si la respuesta resuelve tu problema puedes marcarlo activando la flecha gris a la izquierda de la misma. Saludos.